# Setting headers turns post method into OPTIONS - Angular

Tags: php, angular, http, cors, http-post

I am trying to set header for the authorized user using interceptor. But, setting headers turns post method to options. I have read about preflight requests and cors, but still not able to solve it. Want to know if it is related to me or something should be done from backend .

**P.S: Tested same thing with Postman, works.**

Here is the interceptor where I set headers:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpRequest
} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {AuthService} from "../../auth/auth.service";
@Injectable()
export class SetTokenIfLoggedIn implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let cloneReq = req;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append("api-token", this._authService.getToken())
      .append("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
    if (this._authService.isLogged()) {
      cloneReq = req.clone({
        headers: headers
      });
    }
    return next.handle(cloneReq);
  }
}
```

**Error message:**

[image: This is what I get as response]

**Request headers**

[image: Request:]

**Response headers**

[image: Response]

Comment: @quentin - I know there are lots of posts like this one. But as I mentioned cors settings are set as it's shown. The server responds with 'Acces-Control-Allow-Origin' : *.  Server settings for custom header ('api-token') is also allowed.

Comment: So either you are responding correctly to the OPTIONS request and the browser is then making the POST request and everything is fine … or there is a CORS related error message that you didn't mention in the question.

Comment: @Quentin I have attached error message

Comment: So the server says "400 Method Not Allowed" instead of "200 OK". So you need to fix that.

Comment: That's the point. How?

Comment: We know nothing about the server side code you are trying to POST to.

Comment: So it is related to server, right?